# No sound for the Firebase remote notification in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-notifications

I'm new in iOS development and I'm trying to solve a problem when I send a new notification from my Firebase console to my app there is no sound !

The way to know is to open my phone then I see the notification but there is no sound when the notification arrived !

My code looks exactly like Firebase pre-made code:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift

And i added in my plist.info :

> Required background modes : App downloads content in response to push notifications

Comment: If your app is closed you get the notification but have no sound? Are you trying from firebase console notifications page with advanced option setting: `sound:enabled`. Moreover: are you setting this option during your API call?

Comment: Thank you for the help .. i didn't know there is an advanced option to setting: `sound:enabled` and this solve my problem ❤️

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled the advanced options in the Firebase console and make

> Sound : Enabled
>
> iOS badge : Enabled
>
> Badge Count : 1

And this should solve your problem

Answer (score 4):

in the Firebase console For your Application When you publish notification go to  ---> Additional options
and make ---> sound Enabled
**like image**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lla7R.png)